# Why can't I change or reassign the values of variables in lists using a for loop (python)?

Tags: python

If I have a list of numbers, and I want to increment them using a for loop, why isn't this working:

```
>>> list=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for num in list: 
...  num=num+1
... 
>>> list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I expected to get [2,3,4,5,6].

I know I can get around this by doing

```
>>> newlist=[] 
>>> for num in list: 
...  newlist.append(num+1)
... 
>>> newlist
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

but there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you only get a reference to the variable in the list. When you replace it, you simply change what that reference is pointing to, so the item in the list is left unchanged. The best explanation for this is to [follow it visually](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=old_list%3D%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D%0Afor+num+in+old_list%3A+%0A++++num+%3D+num+%2B+1&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=0) - step through the execution visualization found at that link and it should be very clear.

Note that mutable objects can be mutated in place, and that will affect the list (as the objects themselves will have changed, not just what the name you are working with is pointing to). For comparison, see [the visualization here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=old_list=%5B%5B1%5D,+%5B2%5D,+%5B3%5D,+%5B4%5D,+%5B5%5D%5D%0Afor+num+in+old_list%3a+%0A++++num.append%281%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=0).

The best option here is a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

```
new_list = [num + 1 for num in old_list]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an artifact of how assignment works in python.  When you do an assignment:

```
name = something
```

You are taking the object `something` (which is the result of evaluating the right hand side) and binding it to the name `name` in the local namespace.  When you do your `for` loop, you grab a reference to an element in the loop and then you construct a new object by adding 1 to the old object.  You then assign that new object to the name `num` in your current namespace (over and over again).

If the objects in our original list are mutable, you can mutate the objects in a for loop:

```
lst = [[],[],[]]
for sublst in lst:
    sublst.append(0)
```

And you will see those changes in the original list -- Notice however that we didn't do any assignment here.

Of course, as suggested by lattyware, you can use a list-comprehension to construct a new list:

```
new_list = [x+1 for x in old_list]
```

and you can even make the assignment happen in place:

```
old_list[:] = [x+1 for x in old_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by indexing the array.

```
>>> list=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in range(len(list)): 
...  list[i]=list[i]+1
```

This will circumvent the referencing issue Lattyware spoke of.

Comment: This is a terrible way to loop in Python. I sincerely recommend against ever doing this.

Comment: You can use `enumerate()` here.

Comment: @Lattyware Agreed... I use comprehensions myself, but I wanted to illustrate that indexing the list allows you to change the values directly.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- I've often wondered if `for i,_ in enumerate(...):` is better than `for i in range(len(...)):`.  I suppose `enumerate` works with arbitrary iterables, but in that case, the indices aren't really useful anyway ...

Comment: @mgilson 1. The indices are often useful when iterating - I have many cases where I've needed the index, but usually not for a lookup!  2. I am sure it must be more efficient to use enumerate, because accessing the container with x[i] is an unecessary lookup every time.  And 3. it's _undoubtedly_ better style, because you have the same syntax whether you're iterating generators, lists, or whatever iterable

Comment: @wim -- I would argue that doing either for this example is not the way to go ...

Comment: I agree, in this example!  My beef was with your statement "the indices aren't really useful [when iterating arbitrary iterables] anyway".  I have on many occasions needed those indices for reasons other than a lookup.

Comment: @wim I believe he meant within the context of this question. `enumerate()` is definitely useful for things outside of indexing (if it wasn't, it probably wouldn't exist, or at least wouldn't be a built-in). If you need numbers with the items, great, but I die a little every time I see someone new iterating over a list with indices in Python.