# Replace word w.r.t word in another column using Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, levenshtein-distance

Suppose I have a dataframe `df1`:

```
Sr       A              B                            C
1      rains         It rain there.             It rains there
2      plane         This is a vertical planes  This is a vertical plane
3      tree          Plant a trees              Plant a tree
```

Column `C` is my expected output. I need to compare each word in strings of column B with the word in A and replace it if Levenshtein distance is 1.

**My approach**:

```
import jellyfish as jf
def word_replace(str1):
    comp = #don't know how to store value of column A in this variable.
    for word in str1.split():
        if jf.levenshtein_distance(word,comp) == 1:
           word = comp
        else:
            pass
    return str1

df1['C'] = df1['B'].apply(word_replace)
```

Second thing , what if column `A` has double words like `"near miss"`? How will I need to modify the above code? E.g.:

```
 Sr       A              B                            C
  1     near miss        that was a ner mis          that was a near miss
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with your approach? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: no error yet , i'm yet to figure out how to store the corresponding value of column A in the variable comp .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You have asked two questions in one which is never a good idea on Stack Overflow. I'm just going to reply to your first question, if you want someone to look at your second problem then I suggest you write a new question specifically for it.*

[`pd.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) can work either across rows or across columns, you wish to work on each row individually and so you must pass the `axis=1` keyword argument.

Below is some code that solves your problem, it uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) making use of a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to choose which words need replacing. This list is then joined together using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Originally your code was iterating over the split strings but that will not work [as you cannot modify them as you are iterating over the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846951/why-cant-i-change-or-reassign-the-values-of-variables-in-lists-using-a-for-loop). It was also assuming that the input to the function would be a string, this is incorrect as instead it will be a `pandas.Series` object.

This is a simplified piece of code and does not take into account things like punctuation, that I leave as an exercise to the reader.

```
import pandas as pd
import jellyfish as jf

data1 =  {'A':['rains','plane','tree'],'B':['It rain there','This is a vertical planes','Plant a trees']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

def word_replace(row):
    comp = row['A']
    str1 = row['B']

    out = ' '.join([comp if jf.levenshtein_distance(word, comp) == 1
                    else word for word in str1.split()])
    return out

df1['C'] = df1.apply(word_replace, axis=1)
```