# How to remove double quotes from strings in a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I am trying to get some data in a list of dictionaries.
The data comes from a csv file so it's all string.
the the keys in the file all have double qoutes, but since these are all strings, I want to remove them so they look like this in the dictionary:

```
{'key':value}
```

instead of this

```
{'"key"':value}
```

I tried simply using string = string[1:-1], but this doesn's work...

Here is my code:

```
csvDelimiter = ","
tsvDelimiter = "\t"
dataOutput = []

dataFile = open("browser-ww-monthly-201305-201405.csv","r")

for line in dataFile:
    line = line[:-1]    # Removes \n after every line

    data = line.split(csvDelimiter)

    for i in data:
        if type(i) == str:    # Doesn't work, I also tried if isinstance(i, str)
                              # but that didn't work either.
            print i
            i = i[1:-1]
            print i
    dataOutput.append({data[0] : data[1]})

dataFile.close()

print "Data output:\n"
print dataOutput
```

all the prints I get from print i are good, without double quotes, but when I append data to dataOutput, the quotes are back!

Any idea how to make them disappear forever?

Comment: Try i = i.replace('"','')

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846951/why-cant-i-change-or-reassign-the-values-of-variables-in-lists-using-a-for-loop for why you can't iterate over an immutable object and modify it at the same time.

Comment: Use the `csv` module, it'll save you some trouble - it does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, when dealing with CSV files you truly ought to use Python's built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) (linking to Python 2 docs since it seems that's what you're using).

Another thing to note is that when you do:

`data = line.split(csvDelimiter)`

every item in the returned list, if it is not empty, will be strings.  There's no sense in doing a type check in the loop (though if there were a reason to you would use `isinstance`).  I don't know what "didn't work" about it, though it's possible you were using unicode strings.  On Python 2 you can usually use `isinstance(..., basestring)` where `basestring` is a base class for both `str` and `unicode`.  On Python 3 just use `str` unless you know you're dealing with `bytes`.

Answer (score 7):

Strip it. For example:

```
data[0].strip('"')
```

However, when reading cvs files, the best is to use the built-in `cvs` module. It takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You said: "I tried simply using string = string[1:-1], but this doesn't  work...". It seems to work fine for me:

```
In [101]: s="'word'"
In [102]: s[1:-1]
Out[102]: 'word'
```