# CSV File: counting how many times the word "life" appears in a column

Tags: python, csv

```
with open("billboard_songs.csv") as data:
for line in data:
    line_strip = line.split(",")
    if "life" in line[1]:
        continue
    else:
        print(line)
```

What I want to accomplish is to count how many times the word "life" comes up in song titles. The CSV file is as follow: rank, song, artist, year, lyrics, source and it is split by commas (obviously). So we are looking in location [1] with song.

What am I doing wrong? My output gives me a list of songs but none have the word "life" in them.

Comment: you flipped the condition. your code asks for lines that "life" is NOT in the first column. check again.

Comment: What do you mean?!

Comment: You split your dataline into the variable `line_strip`.  Are you sure you shouldn't be testing `if "life" in line_strip[1]:`?  Modified code posted in my answer below.

Comment: WOW! line_strip[1] did the trick :) thank you! now... question. how can I count my output? I got all the songs with the word "life" in it so how can I count all those outputs?

Comment: Just add a counter variable.  Set it to 0 before you loop your data, and increment it in the same part of the code you're printing them out.  Easy squeezie.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I finally got my code to work :)

Comment: You should use the csv module, it's much safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your if and else logic backwards

```
with open("billboard_songs.csv") as data:
    song_count = 0
    for line in data: 
        line_strip = line.split(",") 
        if "life" in line_strip[1]: 
            print(line)
            song_count += 1 
        else: 
            continue
```

Comment: oh! okay I fixed that but now I'm not getting an output?

Comment: Are you sure your dataset has songs with the word "life" in them?

Comment: Yes! So my dataset is the top 100 songs from 1965-2015. I am searching for how many songs have the word "life' in them.

Comment: It might be worth looking at some of the data. I'm wondering if maybe the song titles have the word "Life" and not "life"

Comment: actually, I fixed the error! I was putting line[1] instead of line_strip[1]. Now I just need to count how many outputs I got. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Set a counter variable to 0 outside the loop, and increment it in the same section you are printing the line.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've split your line into the array `line_strip`, so shouldn't your code read:

```
with open("billboard_songs.csv") as data:
for line in data:
    line_strip = line.split(",")
    if "life" in line_strip[1]:
        print(line)
    else:
        continue
        print(line)
```

Comment: thank you Matthew! That did the trick. now... question. how can I count my output? I got all the songs with the word "life" in it so how can I count all those outputs?

Comment: See my comment to your main post/question.

Answer (score 0):

One very important addition that I thought of after the fact is that many song titles actually have commas in them.  The way you are splitting the data lines (by comma) does not take into account that CSV files have both field delimiters (the comma in this case) and text delimiters (usually " character).  So with your data, if the 2001 Roxette song "My World, My Love, My life" was in your list, the CSV file might look like this:

```
rank, song, artist, year, lyrics, source
rank here,"My World, My Love, My Life",Roxette,2001,Lyrics here, Source here
```

Your line `line_strip = line.split(",")` would split that data line into the following:

```
rank here
"My World
 My Love
 My Life"
Roxette
2001
Lyrics here
 Source here
```

Therefore, piece [1] would be `"My World`, and therefore would **not** be returned as having the word life in the title, where, in fact, it clearly does.  This is because you are not reading the .CSV file properly.

When properly reading a .CSV file, a routine needs to know it should only split the line on field delimiters (commas) which do not occur inside of a pair of text delimiters ("), as well as knowing it has to strip off the text delimiters.  My sample data line should properly be split like this:

```
rank here
My World, My Love, My Life
Roxette
2001
Lyrics here
 Source here
```

The best way to do this is to use a more mature CSV reader, such as the built-in python csv module - [see this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123705/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-strings-in-a-list-in-python)

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Matthew! I have another question. It is regarding the same file, but this time we are writing a function for an input of any word to search in the song title and then return the number of songs that contain the word. Any suggestions on where to start? This is mine `import csv
word_count = 0
with open("billboard_songs.csv") as data:
       word = input("Enter any word: ")
       for line in data:
        line_strip = line.split(",")
        if word in line_strip[1]:
            word_count += 0
            print(word_count)`

Comment: ^^^ but my output is 0? Which I know isn't correct.

Comment: Believe it or not, I am actually not a python programmer (Mostly VB/VBA, PowerShell and a bit of C#).  Without seeing the contents of the .csv I can't really tell you if you should or should not be getting 0, and there isn't anything I can tell that is "wrong" with your code from my limited Python ability.

Comment: Sorry about that! Well you were very helpful with your limited Python ability. I found my error too so now I'm not getting 0!

Comment: Good news!  Glad I could help some at least.