# Reverse keys and values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'absorbed': ['ah0', 'b', 'z', 'ao1', 'r', 'b', 'd', '#'],
'access': ['ae1', 'k', 's', 'eh1', 's', '#'],
 ...}
```

I want to reverse each key and value to get next dictionary:

```
dict = {'debrosba': ['#', 'd', 'b', 'r', 'ao1', 'z', 'b', 'ah0'],
'ssecca': ['#', 's', 'eh1', 's', 'k', 'ae1'],
 ...}
```

and than put symbol "#" at the end of list.

I tried:

```
for word in words:
    word[::-1]
    word = word[1:] + word[1]
    print word
```

for keys 
and

```
for word in words.values():
    word = word[::-1]
    symbol = word.pop(0)
    print word.append(symbol)
```

but have got `None`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I change or reassign the values of variables in lists using a for loop (python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846951/why-cant-i-change-or-reassign-the-values-of-variables-in-lists-using-a-for-loop)

Comment: You get `None` because `print word.append(symbol)` returns `None` . You have to print the list after appending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Татьяна Паскевич, try this:

```
d1 = {'absorbed': ['ah0', 'b', 'z', 'ao1', 'r', 'b', 'd', '#'],
  'access': ['ae1', 'k', 's', 'eh1', 's', '#']}
d2 = {}
for a in d1:
    d2[a[::-1]] = d1[a][::-1]
print d2
```

Output:

```
{'ssecca': ['#', 's', 'eh1', 's', 'k', 'ae1'], 'debrosba': ['#', 'd', 'b', 'r', 'ao1', 'z', 'b', 'ah0']}
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

My solution: iterate items of the dict to inverse keys and values (lists)

```py
fdict = {'absorbed': ['ah0', 'b', 'z', 'ao1', 'r', 'b', 'd', '#'],
'access': ['ae1', 'k', 's', 'eh1', 's', '#']}

dict_= {v[::-1]: k[::-1] for v, k in fdict.items()}
print dict_

>> {'debrosba': ['#', 'd', 'b', 'r', 'ao1', 'z', 'b', 'ah0'],'ssecca': ['#', 's', 'eh1', 's', 'k', 'ae1']}
```

Comment: Your first version was correct, why the strange juggling with the value now?

Comment: You are no longer reversing the list. You are concatenating the first element with the middle with the last element. You created a copy, in a hugely round-about way.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood what he wants

Comment: I don't think they understand what they want. The sample output uses simple reversal.

Comment: @WajdiFarhani it's still not correct `print dict= {v[::-1]: k[::-1] for v, k in fdict.items()}` is not valid syntax...

Comment: One last detail: don't use `dict` as a variable name; that masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Wajdi Farhani, who got here first.

As for the second part:

```
rd = {k[::-1]: (v[-2::-1] + v[-1:]) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

Note that this only works if the `'#'` is initially always the first item in the source lists.